# How to multiply a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, multiplication

I want to multiply a tuple.

```
y = 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1
x = {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 3, 4), ('S', 'C', 'T'): (0.4. 0.1, 0.3, 3,1)}
```

Expected output:

```
res = {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (0.02, 0.02, 0.18, 1.2, 0.4), ('S', 'C', 'T'): (0.04. 0.02, 0.06, 1.2, 0.1)}
```

My code is:

```
from fuctools import partial:
res = {}
keys = list(set.keys())
vals = list(set.values())
mul = lambda x, y: x*y
for n in vals:
   res.extend(map(partial(mul, x), y))
res = dict(res)
print(res)
```

But it causes an error that the dict has no attribute `'extend'`.

Comment: what's the logic?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
y = 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1
x = {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 3, 4), ('S', 'C', 'T'): (0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 3,1)}

for k, v in x.items():
    x[k] = tuple(v[i] * y[i] for i in range(len(y)))
```

Or alternatively (as Alex Hall suggested in the comment below) you could use the `zip` function like this:

```
for k in x.keys():
    x[k] = tuple(a[0] * a[1] for a in zip(y, x[k]))
```

I would suggest using one of the above instead of your original approach. But for future reference, the reason you are getting the error `dict has no attribute 'extend'` is that `extend()` is a method for lists, not for dictionaries. When you attempt to call `res.extend()` it is throwing this exception because `res` is a `dict`, not a `list`. If you want to add multiple key/value pairs to a dict, use the [`update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) method.

Comment: This is good but I would suggest using some longer names and `zip`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Alex. I agree re: longer names and if I had more context on what the application is for, I would use more expressive names. And good call on using zip - I didn't think of that and it definitely is more readable than range(len(y))

Comment: thank you very much this helper my question..
if sum of res `(0.02, 0.02, 0.18, 1.2 , 0.4)` be `(1.82)` how about it? I tried using add and sum but not work.

Comment: To sum up a list of numbers you just do `sum(the_list_of_numbers)`. For examples `sum([1,2,3])` or `a = [5,6,7,8]; sum(a)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `starmap()` with the operator `mul` inside a dictcomp:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import mul

y = 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1
x = {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 3, 4), ('S', 'C', 'T'): (0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 3, 1)}

{k: tuple(starmap(mul, zip(v, y))) for k, v in x.items()}
# {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (0.020000000000000004, 0.020000000000000004, 0.18000000000000002, 1.2000000000000002, 0.4), ('S', 'C', 'T'): (0.04000000000000001, 0.020000000000000004, 0.06, 1.2000000000000002, 0.1)}
```

Alternatively you can use `numpy.multiply()`:

```
import numpy as np

y = 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1
x = {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): (0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 3, 4), ('S', 'C', 'T'): (0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 3, 1)}

{k: np.multiply(v, y) for k, v in x.items()}
# {('S', 'A', 'C', 'T'): array([0.02, 0.02, 0.18, 1.2 , 0.4 ]), ('S', 'C', 'T'): array([0.04, 0.02, 0.06, 1.2 , 0.1 ])}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do like follow

```
from itertools import starmap
import operator
final_dict = { key: list(starmap(operator.mul, zip(value, y))) for key, value in x.items() }
for key, value in final_dict.items():
   print(value)
```